# extract current date and current year from varchar on MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, varchar

How I make to get back login and nb_match over the year and the current month of my table?

this is my query for all matching without the month ....

```sql
SELECT login, SUM(column1) 
FROM 'my_table'
NATURAL JOIN 'join_table' 
GROUP BY login
```

(`at_limitation_admin` is the natural join on 'login' column). 'month' is varchar column. (example 2009/03)

Comment: GROUP BY login,month?

Comment: but the collumn month is varchar. I want to sort out my query with the current month and the current year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pull the month out of the varchar field use:

```
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`month`,'%Y/%m'))
```

I don't fully understand your end goal, I can add info if needed.

Edit:

You can use this WHERE clause get results for current month and year

```
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`month`,'%Y/%m')) = MONTH(NOW())
  AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`month`,'%Y/%m')) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: I want login and nb_matching from the current month and year but the column which contain the date (month) is varchar how can I extract this ?